# About block scope chaining, no error, no warning, but the result is surprised and I can not figure out why

Tags: c, scope

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int count = 22;
  {
    int count = count * 2;
    printf("inner: %d\n", count);
  }
  printf("outer: %d\n", count);
  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
inner: 65532
outer: 22
```

The output is surprised, I can not figure out why.

edit: compile method: gcc test.c

Comment: it could be an interesting job-interview question - what should be the value of an uninitialized `int` variable, on a 2s-complement platform where `sizeof(int)` is 32 bits, such that multiplying it by itself gives 65532?

Comment: In other words, since 65532 is not a perfect square, we're looking for a 64-bit perfect square, whose lower 32 bits are `0000FFFC` (65532).

Comment: I don't think it should be a square, but just double the uninitialized value (327866?). Anyway have you took care of the warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> int count = count * 2;
> ```

in `count * 2` *count* is not initialized because it is the inner *count*,  not the outer *count* as you probably supposed

so your code is equivalent to

```
int main(void) {
  int outer_count = 22;
  {
    int inner_count = inner_count * 2;
    printf("inner: %d\n", inner_count);
  }
  printf("outer: %d\n", outer_count);
  return 0;
}
```

but not to

```
int main(void) {
  int outer_count = 22;
  {
    int inner_count = outer_count * 2;
    printf("inner: %d\n", inner_count);
  }
  printf("outer: %d\n", outer_count);
  return 0;
}
```

> no warning

I do not know what compiler and options you use, but :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
c.c: In function ‘main’:
c.c:6:9: warning: ‘count’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
     int count = count * 2;
         ^~~~~
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: I got it, `int a = a * 2` is valid in C. It is a little surprised, do you know more about this?

Comment: @LiuXiMin I agree with you this is *disturbing*, but may be goal was to be able to do something like `int a = 1, b = a*2;` so a variable exist just after it is declared. After all `int a = a * 2` is just a shortcut of `int a; a = a * 2`

Comment: I just gcc test.c, no warning, and I try your -Wall flag, get warning. I am new to C, not familiar to these flags. Looks -Wall is a good flag ;-)

Comment: @LiuXiMin I encourage you to always use the option `-Wall` at minimum and may be `-Wall -pedantic` or `-Wall -pedantic -Werror` to be sure to not miss a warning